# How to lauch another channel(B) from current channel(A) in ROKU

Tags: roku, brightscript

1. Show all channels
2. Clicking on channel takes the user to channel if installed
3. If not installed, allow the user to install.

   if  IsChannelIstalled(channelID) then 
     ECP_Command(“launch/channelID?contentID=deep_link_param) 
   else 
     ECP_Command(“install/channelID?contentID=deep_link_param) 
   end if

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: is this a homework or an interview question?! i mean you obviously know what has to be done, you just enumerated the steps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that might help you:

```
sub launchChannel(channelId as String, params = "" as String)
    urlTransfer = createObject("roURLTransfer")
    ipAddress = createObject("roDeviceInfo").getIPAddrs().eth0

    url = "http://" + ipAddress + ":8060/launch/" + channelId

    if params.len() > 0
        url = url + "?" + params
    end if

    urlTransfer.setURL(url)
    urlTransfer.postFromString("")
end sub
```

For more info check [External Control Guide](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/External+Control+Guide).